# Getting random junk output from my simple syscall test

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls

Using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.0.21+ x86_64)

I created a simple syscall and am trying to pass input (the integer 5) through it by calling it in a c program and then see if I can get the input back out.  I keep getting random junk as my output rather than my input.

Simple system call:

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/sched.h>
#include<linux/syscalls.h>
#include<linux/signal.h>
#include "tags.h"

asmlinkage int sys_get_tag(int pid)
{
  return pid;
}
```

my userspace test code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    int pid = syscall(335, 5); // 335 is the syscall number, 5 is the input to the syscall that I am trying to return
    printf("return: %d \n", pid);
    return 0;
}
```

my output:

```
return: 4980568
```

I get it to work when I return some integer in my syscall, like return 5; for example; so I know the syscall is being used.

Comment: A good start would be to put a `printk` in your `sys_get_tag` function to see if it is actually being called, and if so, what argument it is receiving.

Comment: Please, into the question post add the **version** of Linux kernel you use. This is also noted in the description for [tag:linux-kernel] tag.

Comment: Also the architecture: x86-32, x86-64, or something else?

Comment: added the version to the top of my post, and tried out the printk statement.  It outputs the same junk that my test code does, so the wrong thing may be getting passed in.

Comment: That kernel/arch combination uses syscall wrappers. Your kernel code is out of date.

Comment: Got it to work by using SYSCALL_DEFINE1(get_tag, int, pid) rather than using asmlinkage int sys_get_tag(int pid)